# SSAS Programmatically Create Tables

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I'm trying to create an SSAS Tabular Model to be used by Power BI Embedded, modelling data from an application that uses an EAV Database (For Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

I've managed to map out the set of tables, using M queries to mould and pivot the tables as required. But the problem I'm facing is that our application allows users to create new entities and therefore the source data is fluid.

As an example, imagine the data has two tables:

```
EntityTypes
Car
Boat
Plane
```

And these entities attributes are held in another table:

```
EntityID    EntityType  Attribute       Value
1           Car         #Seats          4
1           Car         Transmission    Manual
1           Car         Make            Ford
2           Car         Make            Honda
2           Car         Transmission    Auto
3           Boat        #Engines        2
3           Boat        Berths          4
4           Plane       EngineType      Jet
4           Plane       Manufacturer    Boeing
5           Boat        #Engines        2
6           Plane       #Engines        4
```

Whilst I can create a Car Table, Boat Table and Plane Table in SSAS through pivoting, the problem I'm facing is when the application user creates a new Entity, how can a new table in the model be created to handle the change? I'm trying to avoid the need for a human in our support team to need to edit the SSAS model whenever this happens.

Does anyone know of a way to dynamically create tables in an SSAS model so that if a new row appears in the EntityType table at processing, a new table is created in the model?

My current theory is to split the EAV table in SSIS and using TMSL in a loop to create the model tables but I wanted to check first before I disappeared down that rabbit hole for days.

Comment: Why would you need to create a separate table for each entity? It makes no sense. Just create a star schema and you  are done.

Comment: The main problem with keeping a common fact table is that once you pivot the actual table I'm working with, there are 200+ columns as all the attributes created for the entities would be in the same table. On each row, most of the fields would be null. The current import process I have is that each table filters the EAV table by the EntityType column, then pivots the table on Attribute to give a workable table.

Comment: Fact table should not contain any attributes, they should be moved into their own dimensions. I would re-visit the design of your dimensional model. The approach of multiple tables per entity seems conceptually wrong.

Comment: Yup, I probably misunderstood, but if each of the entities should be moved into their own separate Dimension, don't I run into the issue of how to automatically create a new Dimension when a new Entity is created in the source data?

Comment: You should not create any new tables for new entities. Your model can have a dimension "Entity", a dimension "Attribute", and a fact table, say, "Entity Configurations". The latter will consist of Entity_Key, Attribute_Key, and Value. When a new entity or attribute are added to the source data, the model's content is updated, but its structure remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the discussion of whether or not it's a good idea to allow users to dynamically add tables and data to a model, the answer to your question is as follows:

Sure! Assuming you're on SQL Server 2016 (or newer), there are a couple of ways to programatically alter your model (adding tables, removing columns, changing measure expressions, etc...).

- [Tabular Model Scripting Language (TMSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-model-scripting-language-tmsl-reference?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Tabular Object Model (TOM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-model-programming-compatibility-level-1200/introduction-to-the-tabular-object-model-tom-in-analysis-services-amo?view=sql-server-2017)

You could use PowerShell, C# or a script task in SSIS to apply the actual changes to the model through either TMSL or TOM.